# NestJS class-transformer ignoring Declorators on TypeORM-Entity

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, class-transformer

I am trying to use classToPlain on a TypeORM-Entity in a NestJS Project and class Transformer just ignores the @Exclude Declorator. Below are some snippets of my code:

user.entity

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @Column()
  @Exclude()
  password!: string;
}

export const userToPlain = (user : User) => {
  return classToPlain<User>(user);
}
```

user.service

```
  createUser(userDTO : userCreateDTO, role?: RoleType[]) : Promise<User> {
    return new Promise<User>(async (resolve, reject) => 
      this.usersRepository.save(userDTO).then(res => {
        resolve(res);
      }).catch(reject);
    })
  }
```

users.controller

```
@Post("/create")
create(@Body() userDto : userCreateDTO, @Req() request: Request, @Res() res: Response) {
      this.userService.createUser(userDto, ["EDITOR"]).then(newUser => {
        res.status(201);
        res.json(userToPlain(newUser));
      })
  })
}
```

I've neither worked with NestJS, TypeORM, nor class-transformer before, so I really have no clue what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're injecting `@Res()` into your route handler. Nest's docs [explicitly state](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#library-specific-approach) that if you use `@Res()` you are in charge of formatting and sending the response yourself. If you want Nest to handle the response for you, remove `@Res()` from the route handler, and use `@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializationInterceptor)` [as described in the docs here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization)

### Edit 8/3/21 to answer the question

*Apologies, I read the question too quickly and didn't notice that you are indeed calling `res.send` and the `userToPlain` method yourself.*

SO, TypeORM is a little weird with the save method, in that it only returns an object, not a class instance, so there's no metadata to be read in regards to the `classToPlain` method, and as such, it returns the object as is. You can verify this yourself by logging `newUser instanceof User`.

What you can do about this is call `plainToClass` first, so that you get back an actual instance of the `User` class, that can then be properly serialized in the `userToPlain` method. You can put this in your `useToClass` method, or make it a part of the `UserService#createUser`

Comment: I am formating the object myself in userToPlain which calls class to plain

Comment: Apologies, you're correct. I've updated my answer with my findings and solution